# Unable to add ppa while php installation in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, upgrade

I am trying to install php7.2 in ubuntu 16.04. while adding third party repository to upgrade 7.2. I am using command like below:

```
       sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

But it is not working. It is showing error

```
       cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ondrej/ubuntu/php'.
       ERROR: '~ondrej' user or team does not exist .
```

Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/944782/630825

Comment: @Rahul I have checked this,but not find any solution

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/724224/cant-add-ppa-on-ubuntu-15-10-user-or-team-does-not-exist

Comment: @Rahul In above link export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy:port/"
export https_proxy="https://username:password@proxy:port/"

Comment: @Rahul any idea on what is username and password here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

Reinstall certificates

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`

And if you're behind a proxy, set the proxy.

Installing the repo manually did not work, but reinstalling the certs did.